# System freezes while running Tensorflow model training code

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, handwriting-recognition

I am trying to train model for handwritten digits. My data consists of images, each of size 80X80. So I get 6400 features as inputs.
While trying to train model as per code used in https://www.kaggle.com/kakauandme/digit-recognizer/tensorflow-deep-nn, my systems hangs after 200 iterations with training accuracy 0.06.

Why is this happening? I don't get any errors. My system just freezes.
Also, how do I set pooling and convolution layers parameters? Is the problem related to these parameters?

PS: I'm not using GPU.

Comment: BTW, I've seen TensorFlow hang my system when it used too much memory, so you may want to try running it with `top` to see if memory is exploding

Comment: Yes that was my first thought too. But surprisingly, I have a lot of memory still available just before it hangs.

Comment: Hi, @stkusr1234 - if still relevant, can you provide more information about your system?  Windows of Linux?  And when you say freezes - is it just TF, or your entire computer?  (If this isn't relevant still, might be best to close the question if you don't want an answer.)